# So many TCP packets to domain server from domain clients

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tcp

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 which controls my LAN. Everything was working fine (Shared Folders, Folder Redirection and so on) for a two months. But suddenly, there occured delay on communication between client computers and the server. When I look at the 'resmon', some client computers send heavy packets (approximately 9,000,000) to the server. When I look at Network Activity -> Image, it says 'System'. And ping time is '800ms'. At least could anyone give an advise how can I control that packets, which application uses so much traffic ?

Comment: i would disconnect the client that cause this issue

Comment: Have you checked the offending client for malware?

Comment: Now I shrinked my DHCP Scope and right now everything works fine. Again when I widening the scope it crashes all traffic. Again after shrinking it, works fine. (So far my problem has gone, but it does not satisfy)